# Alarm.name always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, alarm

For some reason, even when I create an alarm, the name always returns undefined. I didn't change the code at all because I didn't know what I could do to make it work.

background.js:

```
chrome.alarms.clearAll();
chrome.alarms.create("check-tabs", { periodInMinutes: .01, when: Date.now() + 500 });

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {
    if (alarm.name == "check-tabs") {
        console.log("is check-tabs");

        chrome.tabs.query({ active: false, lastFocusedWindow: false, pinned: false }, function (tabs) {
            var tab;
            for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                tab = toString(tabs[i].id);
                chrome.alarms.create(tab, { when: Date.now() + 30 * 1000 });
                if (typeof chrome.alarms.get(tab).name === 'undefined') {
                     chrome.alarms.create(tab, { when: Date.now() + 30 * 1000 });
                     console.log(tab + " undefined"); //this is printed evry half a second rather than every 30 seconds
                }        
            }
        });
    } else if (alarm.name != "check-tabs") {
        console.log(alarm.name + " not check-tabs");
    }
});
```

manifest.json (in case theres something wrong there):

```
{
    "name": "Tab Timer",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Tab Timer"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content_script.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "alarms",
        "background",
        "storage",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

There was one test I did which was this:

```
chrome.alarms.clearAll();
chrome.alarms.create("rand-alarm", { periodInMinutes: .01, when: Date.now() + 500 });
console.log(chrome.alarms.get("rand-alarm").name);
```

And it still prints `undefined`.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: 1) chrome.alarms.get is asynchronous so it doesn't return the alarm itself, but instead you should use a callback, see the documentation 2) `toString(tabs[i].id)` Should be `tabs[i].id.toString()` or better `${tabs[i].id}`